Montecarlo analysis in Brightway 2.5 using Beta-Pert distribution
This might be a beginner-type question:
I am trying to run a Monte Carlo analysis in Brightway 2.5 using the Beta-PERT distribution and ecoinvent 3.10 (cutoff). However, running even just 100 iterations takes a very long time. For instance, only 10 iterations take 7 minutes, while my goal is to run 10,000 iterations. I was able to pinpoint the issue: as long as my_mc.lci() is within the for loop, the process slows down significantly due to the repetitive recalculation of the inventory. However, as soon as I remove my_mc.lci() from the for loop, I keep getting the same score for every iteration. I've tried nearly every solution I could find online, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks a lot! (I’m using Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda, Python v3.12.7)
#Presetting:

act2 = [x for x in eco_edit if 'carbon black production' in x ['name']
        ] [0]

heat_exchange= list(act2.technosphere())  [1]  
act2.heat_exchange = heat_exchange

#Set up beta-pert distribution since it is not available in stats_arrays
def beta_pert_random(min_val, mode_val, max_val, size=1):
    alpha = 1 + 4 * (mode_val - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)
    beta_param = 1 + 4 * (max_val - mode_val) / (max_val - min_val)
    return beta.rvs(alpha, beta_param, loc=min_val, scale=max_val - min_val, size=size)

#Defining Pert-parameters
min_heat = 0.1  # MJ
mode_heat = 1.5  # MJ (default)
max_heat = 10  # MJ
size = 1   

demand = {act2.id: 1}
     
list_of_methods= [AF, CC, EP, ...]  
CC_method = list_of_methods [1]     #Climate change

#Set up characterization matrix which is calculated once
def get_C_matrix(demand, list_of_methods):
    C_matrix = {}
    sacrificial_LCA = bc.LCA(demand)
    sacrificial_LCA.lci()
    
    CC_method = list_of_methods[1]
    sacrificial_LCA.switch_method(CC_method)
    C_matrix[CC_method] = sacrificial_LCA.characterization_matrix
    
    return C_matrix    


#Monte Carlo Simulation:
my_iterations = 100
mc_scores = np.empty(shape=[my_iterations])
my_C_matrix = get_C_matrix(demand, list_of_methods)[CC_method]

for iteration in range(my_iterations):
    random_heat = beta_pert_random(min_heat, mode_heat, max_heat, size)
    heat_exchange['amount'] = random_heat [0] 
    heat_exchange.save()  

    my_mc = bc.LCA(demand, method=CC_method)
    my_mc.lci()              
    my_mc.lcia()
    
    next(my_mc)

    mc_scores[iteration] = (my_C_matrix * my_mc.inventory).sum()

results = mc_scores.tolist()


in each iteration you're modifying the sql database with your inventory when you do heat_exchange.save(). This is going to be mega slow. It is much better to use an interface with bw_processing. You can create one that in each iteration returns a value from your function and modify the precise value of your A matrix that you want to change.
An example here  or here. You can combine that with the uncertainty coming from your background (ecoinvent) if you want.

Thank you for your advice, it's running much faster now!
